# show a popup div that is bigger that the container

Tags: html, popup

Registration<%=Registeredcandidates %>&nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp  **Coming soon**<%=Registeredcandidates %>%>**** 

 "

```
 <label ><a class ="dashtext" >Training  </a><a  class ="dashtext" style="padding-left: 75px;"><%= Registeredtraining %></a>&nbsp &nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp <img src="Images/preview.png" style="width:18px; height:18px;" class="popTertiary" rel="popover" data-original-title="Request:" data-content="<div ><b>Coming soon<b><%=Registeredcandidates %></b> <span style='color:#0c6197;'></span><br/><b></b><br/> <span style='color:#0c6197;'></span><div>"</label><br /><br />



 <label ><a class ="dashtext" >Employment</a><a  class ="dashtext" style="padding-left: 52px;"><%=RegisteredEmployment%></a>&nbsp &nbsp  &nbsp  &nbsp &nbsp <img src="Images/preview.png" style="width:18px; height:18px;" class="popTertiary" rel="popover" data-original-title="Request:" data-content="<div ><b>Coming soon<b><%=Registeredcandidates %></b> <span style='color:#0c6197;'></span><br/><b></b><br/> <span style='color:#0c6197;'></span><div>"</label><br /><br />
```

$(".popTertiary").popover({ html: true, trigger: 'hover', placement: 'left' });

Comment: l need the div to break out of the container

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please edit your question to fix the display, make it an actual question (you know, with a question mark...) and descibe your problem. If possible, please create a fiddle with it so that we get to see all usefull code (CSS, JS, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Go into your stylesheet and give it a Z-index higher than what you want it to appear over

```
#Div{
    Z-index:3333333;
    }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp